# Adicionar quantidade itens a lista de acordo com o while

Tags: python, while

Quero que o while faça o loop até que a condição seja falsa, porém ele pergunta o nome de dois alunos e simplesmente encerra.

Exemplo - > Coloquei 10 na quantidade de alunos, O while pede 2 vezes o nome e encerra a aplicação.

Code:

```
import os
import time


alunos = []
contador = 0

qtd_alunos = input("Numero de alunos: ")
qtd_alunos = int(qtd_alunos)

while contador <= qtd_alunos:
  aluno_nome = input("Nome aluno: ")
  alunos.append(aluno_nome)
  contador = contador + qtd_alunos
else:
  print("Alunos adicionados.")
  time.sleep(5)
  os.system("cls")

print("Mostrando alunos\n")
for aluno in alunos:
print(f"Nome do aluno: {aluno}")
```

Answer (score -2):

Para obter o resultado esperado o contador deveria ser incrementado em uma unidade a cada iteração, mas ele está sendo incrementando com a quantidade de alunos: `contador = contador + qtd_alunos`. Basta mudar a linha que incrementa o contador para **`contador += 1`**

Comment: Caramba Sales, é verdade; Como não prestei atenção nisso? Pior que eu sabia que tinha algo errado mas não estava conseguindo encontrar aonde haha. Obrigado por me relembrar !

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).